# Are $\sin(\alpha\beta)$ and $\sin(\alpha^{\beta})$ expressible in terms of $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\beta)$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

There is a well known formula for expressing $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ just using $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\beta)$. It is enough to replace $\cos$ in the formula $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)$ by its equivalent form in terms of $\sin$ function. Thus $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ is *expressible* via elementary functions (polynomials, radicals, fractions, ...) and $\sin(\alpha), \sin(\beta)$.

> **Question 1:** What about $\sin(\alpha\cdot\beta)$ and $\sin(\alpha^{\beta})$? Can we express them just using $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\beta)$ (in any non-trivial sense)? If no, how to prove this fact?
>
> **Question 2:** Also we can express $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$ in terms of $\tan(\alpha)$ and $\tan(\beta)$. What about $\tan(\alpha\cdot\beta)$ and $\tan(\alpha^{\beta})$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a constant integer, then you can write $\sin(\alpha\beta)$ using only $\sin\beta$ and $\cos\beta$ (see [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)). But there is no formula for $\sin (\alpha\beta)$ for general $\alpha$ and $\beta$, or for $\sin (\alpha^\beta)$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut How to prove non-existence of such a formula?

Comment: Please help on adding suitable tags for this question.

Comment: For a non integer $\alpha$, you can prove that $\sin(\alpha\beta)$ cannot be written with only algebraic operations, $\sin(\beta)$ and any function of $\alpha$ (call the whole thing $f(\sin\beta,\alpha)$), by considering the periodicity of the functions $\beta\to\sin(\alpha\beta)$ and $\beta\to f(\sin\beta,\alpha)$: the latter is $2\pi$-periodic, not the former. For $\beta\to\sin(\alpha^\beta)$ it's even easier: it's not periodic at all if $\alpha>0$, $\alpha\neq1$.

Answer (score 6):

The underlying reason why you shouldn't expect any such formulas to exist is that $e^{ix}$
is a homomorphism with respect to addition:
$$e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix}\cdot e^{iy}$$
but not with respect to multiplication, and certainly not with respect to exponentiation.
The angle-addition formulae for $\sin$ and $\cos$ come from the homomorphism property:
$$e^{i(x+y)}=\cos(x+y)+i\sin(x+y)$$
$$\begin{align*}
e^{ix}e^{iy}&=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))\\
&=\biggl(\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)\biggr)+i\biggl(\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)\biggr)
\end{align*}$$
(Then just identify the real and imaginary parts.)

Because $e^{ixy}$ is not going to have a relationship with $e^{ix}$ and $e^{iy}$ all the time, perhaps a natural next step would be to relax the question to only being related to one of them, say $e^{ix}$. The only time one could have any hope of a relationship with $e^{ix}$ is if $y$ is an integer, because that is precisely when 
$$e^{ixy}=(e^{ix})^y$$
is true for all $x$ ([see here on complex exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases)). And, naturally, this is precisely the situation when $\sin(xy)$ and $\cos(xy)$ have actual expressions of the sort you want ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles)).